# Variables in time.sleep(x) with praw for Python

Tags: python-3.x, config, reddit, praw

How do I call an integer from a separate file (in the case in the same dir named "config.py") to be used as part of the time.sleep(x) function?

```
print("Sleeping for " + config.timeout + " seconds...")
#Sleep for 10 seconds...
time.sleep(config.timeout)
```

In my case, the top line print's just fine, but the bottom line doesn't register config.timeout as the number in the config file that the top line found just fine.

Comment: execute this: `print(type(config.timeout))`

Answer (score 1):

If the first line ran successfully, it sounds like you are importing the variable correctly, it just is not a Number. To ensure that you can do `time.sleep(Number(config.timeout))`

Also, just in case, to ensure you are correctly importing the variable you can write `from config import timeout` and then use `timeout` within the sleep function.